# How to match a MAC address in mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

Imagine a URL like this:

http://hostname/a/b/xy-00:11:22:33:44:55-/c

I would like to put an .htaccess file in the root and process it as:

http://hostname/d.php, where d.php is really stored in the filesystem as /home/user/d.php

I have the following in my .htaccess file, but a match is not happening, i.e., Apache is saying 404 Not Found.

```
RewriteRule    ^/a/b/xy-(.*)-/c$  ~user/d.php [NE]
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Filesystem layout:

```
\
+etc
| +apache2
|   +httpd.conf
|   +extra
|   | +httpd-userdir.conf
|   +users
|     +user.conf
+Library
| +WebServer
|   +Documents
|     +index.html.en
|     +info.php
+Users
  +user
    +Sites
      +d.php
```

Relevant /etc/apache2/httpd.conf snip (on MacOS X Lion):

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

/Library/WebServer/Documents/.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule    ^/a/b/xy-(.*)-/c$  ~user/d.php [NE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the leading slash in your match:

```
RewriteRule    ^a/b/xy-(.*)-/c$  ~user/d.php [NE]
```

Mod_rewrite removes the leading slash (the prefix) in the URI when you try to match rules within an .htaccess file.